# how should I change my query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I´ve a query that displays data like this:

```
columnA columnB
1         a
1         b
1         c
2         a
2         x
3         z
3         w
```

But I want to show the data like this:

```
columnA columnB
1         a
          b
          c
2         a
          x
3         z
          w
```

Basically on repeated data I want to show an empty cell.
Is it posible?
Here is my original query:

```
SELECT t1.columnnA, t2.columnB
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
GROUP BY t1.columnnA, t2.columnB
ORDER BY t1.columnnA, t2.columnB;
```

How should I change my query?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, which database is this for?  You listed three different ones in your tags.

Comment: It is possible, but consider handling issues of data display at the application level (assuming you have one). Also, in the absence of any aggregating functions the use of GROUP BY is (in my view) inappropriate.

Comment: make it right man! post your tables here, I have no crystal ball!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Oracle flavor:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN rnum = 1 THEN v1.A ELSE NULL END) A, B
  FROM (  SELECT t1.columnA A,
                 t2.columnB B,
                 ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY t1.columnA)
                    rnum
            FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
        ORDER BY t1.columnA, t2.columnB) v1
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93c4c/16)

Answer (score 2):

For mysql you can use variables and `CASE` to check the value is new or repeated

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN @check != columnA THEN columnA END refcolumnA,
columnB,
@check:=columnA
FROM Table1
,(SELECT @check:=0) t
ORDER BY columnA
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed957/4)